# How to get software location and convert it to URI? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have a file named **"Alarm.wav"** and I want to play it with media player, media player can't open a file with getting path, it only gets URI. I rally don't know how to make **this file** location to URI. Furthermore, I need it because software location can change. Here is the code:

```
MediaPlayer alarm = new MediaPlayer();
var uri = new Uri("file://Alarm.wav");
alarm.Open(uri);
alarm.Play();
```

But works if code be like this:

```
MediaPlayer alarm = new MediaPlayer();
var uri = new Uri("file://D:/apps/repos/BorderRaduis/BorderRaduis/bin/Debug/net5.0-windows/Alarm.wav");
alarm.Open(uri);
alarm.Play();
```

Comment: How about `new Uri("Alarm.wav", UriKind.Relative)` or a combination with the current working directory?

Answer (score -1):

Relative path is what you are looking for.

So if you have a folder named e.g. Videos your path should be “videos/alarms.wav”

Comment: so how to use this absolute path?

Comment: “videos/alarms.wav” is not an absolute path.

Comment: relative path is probably what he wanted to say...